# Better coding: simple way to cover all writing possibilities?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing a battleship game to practice. When starting a game, I want to ask a question related to the difficulty of the game, and it goes as follows:

> Let's start a new game. Do you want to play right away? The number of battleships will be randomized, as well as their size (y/n)

When coding the answer I want to identify the yes/no question with all writing possibilities (yes, YES, yES, Yes, etc.) but my code gets like:

```
easy_mode = raw_input("Let's start a new game. Do you want to play right away? The number of battleships will be randomized, as well as their size (y/n)");
if easy_mode == ("yes" or "Yes" or "YES" or "yEs" or "yeS" or "yES" or "YEs" or "YeS"):
(...)
```

It is indeed ugly and I was wondering whether there was an efficient method to do this.

Comment: Not only is it ugly, **it doesn't work**. `('yes' or ...)` evaluates to `'yes'`, so you're really just testing `if easy_mode == 'yes':`.

Comment: Why not a regular expression?  Why English only when you can ask in every language?  Too complicated - you've got bigger problems than this to worry about.

Comment: easy_mode.upper() == "YES"

Comment: @duffymo *"Why not a regular expression?"* - because then you have [two problems](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)!

Comment: Your comment made me laugh @jonrsharpe.  You are perfectly correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're allowing your players to have single character answers as well, put that check in your code too:

```
if easy_mode.lower() in {'yes','y'}:
    (...)
```

Comment: If you make it a set `{'yes', 'y'}` it's slightly more efficient

Answer (score 2):

Try converting it to lowercase and then do checking.

```
easy_mode = raw_input("Let's start a new game. Do you want to play right away? The number of battleships will be randomized, as well as their size (y/n)");
if easy_mode.lower() == 'yes':
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert `easy_mode` string to lower-case and after that you will only need to compare it with full-lowercase version of string, like this:

```
if easy_mode.lower() == 'yes':
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have. You can compare after coverting to the input to lower case or uppercase first.

```
if easy_mode.lower() == "yes"
```

Or,

```
if easy_mode.upper() == "YES"
```